# setTimeout doesn't work with window.location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

i try to rich flash like effect when changing window location, but there is a small problem, i can't solve.

look at the script please

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

            $('a.flash').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('body').fadeOut(1500);
                setTimeout("", 1500);
                window.location=this.href;
            }); 
      });
```

`window.location=this.href` must be done after 1500ms, but it doesn't happen.
could you explain why?
what is strange, when i try to write `alert("something");` instead of `window.location=this.href`, it works fine. Could you explain why?

Thanks

Comment: why it works when i wrote alert()??? in that case it "sleeps" 1500ms, and after it makes alert. why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $('a.flash').click(function(e) {
                var el = this;
                e.preventDefault();
                $('body').fadeOut(1500);
                setTimeout( function() {  location=el.href }, 1500 );
            }); 
      });
```

You're supposed to provide a callback function as the first param of setTimeout which is invoked after 1500 ms.

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout` is *not* equivalent to a `Thread.sleep(1500);` in other languages.  `setTimeout` schedules a piece of code to be run at some point in the future *and does not block*.  Execution immediately passes the `setTimeout` call and continues on.

The first parameter is either a reference to a function or a string that will be evaluated.

See meder's answer for the appropriate way to use `setTimeout`, avoiding evaluation using an anonymous function.

Comment: quotes=eval=badbad, use lambdas instead

Comment: setTimeout("window.location=this.href;", 1500); doesn't work, i tried.
but i inderstand the logic, thanks. but why it works fine, when i wrote alert(); ???

Comment: `this` in that context is probably to `window` and not the `a` element. Have you tried my answer?

Comment: it works, but doesn't understand this.href! so it was redirected to unknown page.

Comment: Did you change the code to `el.href` as in my example and not `this.href` ? You need to cache the `href` because the context in which you provide to setTimeout becomes window and not `a`.

Comment: @meder  your script works, thanks much. i thought the comment was written by Jonathon :DDD